# how to force the browser to list only .xml and .txt files in open dialog?

Tags: javascript, html

Here I am using JSP as front end and struts input tag for uploading file

My need is,
 To force the browser, that only list .xml and .txt extension files  in open dialog and it should be browser independent (support older and newer version browser)

So far I tried this code snippet:

```
<td><html:file property="FileData" accept =".txt,.xml"/></td>
```

It's not working. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think I've understood your question: you want to display the output as an XML element and not HTML?

Comment: when open dialog appears, in that dialog box list or show only .xml and .txt extention files only. do not show all files.

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance at **[The manual](http://devdocs.io/html/element/input)** says that extensions need to include the `.` symbol. So... `accept=".txt,.xml"`.

Comment: yes , i have tried this,,i forgot to put there in question,but the problem is it wont support all browsers.. i want it as browser independent

Comment: @vineeth.soman This is a new feature. It's not available in older browsers.

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this in older browsers and all browsers..

Comment: Unlikely. Look at the linked duplicate at the top of this page.

Answer (score 0):

Notice dots preceeding file extensions, dots are required for it to work.

```
<form action="some_action.asp">
  <input type="file" name="attachment" accept=".xml, .txt">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```